How to improve random access of a video frame with Python?
I'm using pims library (https://github.com/soft-matter/pims) to access frames from .MOV file with over 25K frames, 3840 × 2160, H.264 (High Profile), 60fps.
import pims
from time import perf_counter

video = pims.Video('video/v1.MOV')
t0 = perf_counter()
img = video[1000]
t1 = perf_counter()
print(f'{(t1-t0):.3f}s  {img.shape}')

Here are the timings on a fairly fast PC, after file open:

frame #100: 2.97s
frame #1,000: 28.39s
frame #10,000: 280.19s

AFAIK, this library uses ffmpeg, which can access frame #10,000 with ffmpeg -ss 00:02:46.66 -i v1.MOV -frames:v 1 f10k.png practically instantaneously. Is there a way to improve frame access with pims or some other method?

you can make a function which uses ffmpeg (via a subprocess call) to extract the frame into a png on disk and then load it into memory. This won't get you optimal performance, as there will be subprocess, ffmpeg, and disk overhead.

@bar9833625 Yes, but I would rather use a more direct method. First, I would like to exclude a possibility that I'm using pims in a wrong way.

The pyav package seems to be what you need

pyav is installed. Do I have to do anything to make pims aware of it?

I tried a few options and OpenCV solved my problem. This script:
import cv2
from time import perf_counter

video = cv2.VideoCapture('video/v1.MOV')
t0 = perf_counter()
video.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 10000)
ret, frame = video.read()
t1 = perf_counter()
print(f'{(t1-t0):.3f}s  {ret}  {frame.shape}')

shows frame access time of about 0.2s, regardless of frame number. Bye, bye pims.
There is a downside of this approach, though. The frame indexing is not guaranteed to be accurate: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/9053.
